# Bivariate Probability question

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be the time (in minutes) that John spends waiting for a bus on his way home from uni, and let$ Y$ be the time he spends waiting for a train. $X$ and  $  Y$ have joint density function,$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=0.01e^{-0.1(x+y)}\quad x>0,y>0$$

**i)** Determine the probability that John has to wait less than half an hour in total.

I did $\int_{0}^{30} 0.01e^{-0.1z} dz \approx 0.09 $

**ii)** Find the expected time that John spends waiting for a bus.

Is it $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\; f_{X}(x) dx $ or can I somehow infer this from the exponential distribution.

**iii)** Find $f_{Y}(y)$ .

I am pretty confident this is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 0.01e^{-0.1(x+y)} dx $

**iv)** Find $f_{Y|X} (y|x)$.

Is this just the joint density divided by marginal density of X?

**v)** Are X and Y independent? Give reasons.

I wanted to know if I'm on the right track as I have no solutions to these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**i.)**

Your first result is wrong because the question is related to the total waiting time,   $X+Y$:

$$P(X+Y<30)=\iint_{\{(x,y):x+y<30\}}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ \ dxdy=$$
$$=\frac{1}{100}\int_0^{30} e^{-\frac{1}{10}x}\int_0^{30-x}e^{-\frac{1}{10}y}dydx=$$
$$=\frac{1}{10}\int_0^{30} e^{-\frac{1}{10}x}\left[1-e^{-\frac{1}{10}(30-x)} \right]dx=$$
$$=\frac{1}{10}\left(\int_0^{30}  e^{-\frac{1}{10}x}dx-e^{-3}\int_0^{30}  1\ dx\right)=$$
$$=1-e^{-3}-3e^{-3}.
$$

**ii.)**

The expectation of an exponential distribution equals the reciprocal of its parameter $\lambda=\frac{1}{10}$, that is $E[X]=10$.

**iii.)**

No. The marginal distribution of $Y$ is

$$f_Y(y)=\int_0^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx=\frac{1}{10}e^{-\frac{1}{10}y}.$$

Also

$$f_X(x)=\int_0^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy=\frac{1}{10}e^{-\frac{1}{10}x}.$$

**iv.)**
By the definition:
$$f_{Y|X}(y)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}=f_Y(y).$$

**v.)**

See p.ex. the previous result which is a consequence of the fact that the joint didtribution equals the product of the marginals.